# Text Recognition in Vision Framework: Issue with Multiple Languages

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, vision, text-recognition

I'm developing an iOS application that uses the Vision framework for Optical Character Recognition (OCR). I have set up a VNRecognizeTextRequest to recognize text from images, and I've specified multiple recognition languages. Here's my code:

```swift
import Vision

let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
    if let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] {
        let recognizedStrings = results.compactMap { observation in
            observation.topCandidates(1).first?.string
        }
                    
        print(recognizedStrings)
    }
}
        
request.recognitionLanguages = ["ja-JP", "ru-RU", "ko-KR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES"]
request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
```

However, I've noticed that text recognition works perfectly for all languages except for Korean ("ko-KR") and Russian ("ru-RU").

Interestingly, when I set the **recognitionLanguages** array to contain only "ko-KR" or "ru-RU", text recognition works perfectly for these languages. Here's the code:

```swift
request.recognitionLanguages = ["ko-KR"] // or ["ru-RU"]
```

I'm trying to understand why this is happening. Could there be conflicts or confusion when the Vision framework tries to recognize text in multiple languages simultaneously, especially if the languages use different scripts or have similar characters? How does the Vision framework process multiple languages, and is there a way to improve text recognition for Korean and Russian when multiple languages are specified?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: still an issue?